# security passwords min-length <x>

Tags: security, passwords, cisco-router

Dear superuser members,

I have been trying to set a minimum length for passwords stored in routers, switches and ASA simulated in Cisco Packet Tracer 7.2. I have read in many threads that the command is security passwords min-length 8 but it seems security is not a key word. I have been looking for suitable keywords in all the menus, but I still didn't find a way to set the minimum.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be happening?

Thanks you all!

Comment: You have tried to enter the command in the global configuration mode, right?

Comment: yes, I did. I have tried all modes. I have also looked for similar key words using "?" in each mode.

Comment: Hmm... Then are you sure Packet Tracer supports this feature? All features of real routers are not available.

Comment: Right, it seems it is not implemented. Thanks!